# Hunspell: encoding of personal dictionary

Tags: microsoft-windows, character-encoding, ispell

I am using hunspell 1.3.2 (on Windows) for spell checking, and I've been trying to make a personal dictionary. It works just fine, except the encoding is garbled. Whether I encode the personal dictionary in UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (I'm using the French dictionary as the main one, and it's encoded with that), words with accents are not recognized correctly (words without accents work just fine). What should I do to make it work?

Note: it seems to work fine when I fire up hunspell in a terminal.

---

Even stranger: when I put in the personal dictionary a word containing a character not present in ISO-8859-1 (eg. `ć`), then spell checking works for that word!

Comment: Does the encoding of the dictionary match that of the document you are checking?